# What is the problem with my sudoku finder?

Tags: python, sudoku

For Code Signal I have submitted a solution to the sudoku2 problem. However, this works for all test cases except one where a number repeats in a 3 by 3 block in the middle of the puzzle and the function returns true instead of false.

The program should first check if all the rows and columns have different numbers by using checkRows and checkColumns. Then, it repeats check3by3 for each each 3 by 3 block of numbers. It iterates each the column by 3 each time the block is checked and then it iterates by 3 for the rows when the column reaches its limit. The check3by3 function creates a set for numbers already in the block and adds numbers to the set if it didn't repeat. If the number is repeated, the number will be in the set and the function will return false.

```
def sudoku2(grid):
    if checkRows(grid) and checkColumns(grid):
        for i in range(0,len(grid),3):
            for j in range(0,len(grid),3):
                if check3by3(grid , i + 3, j + 3):
                    return True

    return False

def checkRows(puzzle):
    for list in puzzle:
        s = set()
        for item in list:

            if item in s:
                return False

            elif item == '.':
                pass

            else:
                s.add(item)

    return True


def checkColumns(puzzle):
    for i in range(len(puzzle)):
        s2 = set()
        for j in range(len(puzzle)):
            if puzzle[j][i] in s2:
                return False
            elif puzzle[j][i]  == '.':
                pass
            else:
                s2.add(puzzle[j][i])

    return True

def check3by3(puzzle , row , column):
    set3 = set()
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(column):
            if puzzle[i][j] in set3:
                return False
            elif puzzle[i][j] == '.':
                pass
            else:
                set3.add(puzzle[i][j])

    return True
```

What can I do to my program to fix this problem?

Comment: Test case which wasn't working if anyone is wondering: [[".",".",".",".",".",".","5",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."], 
 ["9","3",".",".","2",".","4",".","."], 
 [".",".","7",".",".",".","3",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."], 
 [".",".",".","3","4",".",".",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".","3",".",".","."], 
 [".",".",".",".",".","5","2",".","."]]

Comment: how does your program behave? how it should in your opinion? please, be more informative

Comment: + update your answer. Don't mess up in comments because you rushed your question.

Comment: I'm confused by the loop bounds in check3by3, it should check a 3x3 area (right?) but it makes no attempt to iterate over a 3x3 area.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're trying to run `check3by3()` function 3 times inside the `for` loop, but you're returning from `sudoku2()` function after the first call returns True. You're not even getting to second or third row of 3x3 grids. I'd recommend to check for a `False` return value from check3by3, and have `sudoku2()` return `True` only if it actually runs all the way through the loop.

Once you've solved that, the next issue you're going to face is an issue with `range()` in your `check3by3()` function. If you only provide one argument to `range()`, it will check every value from 0 to the value you passed it. So on your first loop, you pass it `range(3)`, which will work fine, since you want to check rows 0, 1 and 2. But once you get to the next row of grids, you'll be calling `range(6)`, where you'll be checking all the rows from 0-5.

What you need to do here is, instead of adding 3 to the `check3by3` call, just pass the unmodified row and column number, then instead of calling `range(row)` and `range(column)`, you want to call `range(row, row+3)` and `range(column, column+3)`. This way, when you check the second row of 3x3 blocks, you will be iterating through `range(3, 6)` (3, 4, 5) instead of `range(6)` (0, 1, 2,... 5)

I can't guarantee you won't run into more problems after that; I didn't look super thoroughly at the whole program, but this should set you on the right path to solving your immediate question.